# What best practices or access control models are recommended for implementing fine-grained access control

Tags: access-control, rbac, abac, casbin

We are currently building a webapp, which has several user roles. Each user has one or more roles assigned, which grants them permission to interact with specific parts (REST resources) of the webapp. For example, a user with role `admin` is allowed to perform a `create` action on the resource `user`.

We have implemented this access control using RBAC with [Casbin](https://casbin.org/). This has suited our access control needs until now. We have arrived at the point where we have to implement some kind of mechanism, which enables users of our webapp to grant access to other users for specific data objects (for example their address). In some cases these other users also need to be able to mutate this data.

I have a feeling RBAC is not meant for this level of fine-grained access control. Therefore I am looking for best practices/alternative access control models which are suited for this use case.

I read about ABAC [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28896840), but still have the following 2 questions:

1. Is ABAC still a recommended model, or are there other models I should know about?
2. If I end up using ABAC, what is the best way to combine this with RBAC?

I much appreciate any responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Casbin author. Recently, Casbin adds support for scaling ABAC rules: https://casbin.org/docs/en/abac#scaling-the-model-for-complex-and-large-number-of-abac-rules. Now you can write very powerful ABAC rules within Casbin. You can also mix RBAC and ABAC together inside Casbin.

Comment: Thanks for the link, will look into it.